# How to move the "re-frame-10x" window back to the browser tab after being popping out into a new window?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, window, clojurescript, re-frame

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command `cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, choosing `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the building option.

The application loads in `localhost:3005` with a debugging dashboard. Apparently, this UI is called "re-frame-10x":

[image]

After clicking on the up-right arrow icon on the top-right:

[image]

I managed to pop out the debugging dashboard into a new window in **Google Chrome**. It was injecting some CSS and hiding a button on the webpage. Hence, I decided to "remove it" by popping-it out.

But, I would like to move it back to the browser tab that has `localhost` on the address. How to do it?

Comment: Just close that window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @eugene-pakhomov, it was just closing that window. I must highlight that I had tried that before, the only problem was that there were multiple windows of that type. And all of them need to be closed for the process to work!

Not sure why the program opens multiple windows...